# Css image positions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help[image: align.png] to create image alignment like the one in the image.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can u make a snippet?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex;` to set them in same line and set  `margin-top` to wanted img

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
}
img{
width:337px;
height:235px;
padding: 5px;
}
.down{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" class="down"/>
  <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**With boostrap 3 as your comment:**

See here:https://jsfiddle.net/bfcs2670/2/

```css
.down{
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <img class="Asset-99" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" style="width: 100%"> 
      </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-4 down"> 
        <img class="Asset-100" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" style="width: 100%;"> </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <img class="Asset-101" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" style="width: 100%"> 
      </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use bootstrap just apply `margin` to wanted img

Comment: But, I need it to be responsive.

Comment: see my edit please